# calendar.hour to be incremented by 24

Tags: servlets

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");    
Date d1 = new Date();     
Calendar cl = Calendar. getInstance();
cl.setTime(d1);    
String tim=dateFormat.format(d1); //2014/08/06 15:59:48
System.out.println("today is " + tim);     
System.out.println("today is " + d1.toString());      
cl. add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
```

Here I am increasing minute by 1.
I want to increase hour by 24 i.e. want it to give me next date what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using following:

```
cl.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
```